# How to define the ' assume_role_policy' in terraform?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Here is my aws_iam_role definition in terraform

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "server_role" {
  name = "server-role"

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
        "sts:AssumeEnvironment",
        "sqs:ChangeMessageVisibility",
        "sqs:ReceiveMessage",
        "sqs:SendMessage",
        "s3:GetObject*",
        "s3:ListBucket*",
        "s3:PutBucket*",
        "s3:PutObject*"
      ],
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Sid": ""
    }
  ]
}
EOF
```

but i got this error when I try to run `terraform plan`:

> Error: Error applying plan:
>
> 1 error(s) occurred:
>
> - aws_iam_role.server_role: 1 error(s) occurred:
> - aws_iam_role.server_role: Error creating IAM Role server-role: MalformedPolicyDocument: AssumeRole policy may
>     only specify STS AssumeRole actions.  status code: 400, request id:
>     55f1bfaf-a121-11e9-acaf-bb57d635757b

I basically want to allow the server to read/write S3 buckets and read/write SQS queues.

Apparently I cannot add all these `sqs:*` and `s3:*` in the same place. How can I do it in terraform?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you are confused IAM Policy and IAM assume role Policy.
Try like below. It will create IAM Profile for EC2 and you can attach it to your EC2 instances.

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "server_role" {
  name = "server-role"

  path = "/"

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_iam_policy" "server_policy" {
  name        = "server_policy"
  path        = "/"
  description = "TBD"

  policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
        "sqs:ChangeMessageVisibility",
        "sqs:ReceiveMessage",
        "sqs:SendMessage",
        "s3:GetObject*",
        "s3:ListBucket*",
        "s3:PutBucket*",
        "s3:PutObject*"
      ],
      "Resource": [
          "*"
      ]
      ,
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Sid": ""
    }
  ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "server_policy" {
  role       = "${aws_iam_role.server_role.name}"
  policy_arn = "${aws_iam_policy.server_policy.arn}"
}

resource "aws_iam_instance_profile" "server" {
  name = "server_profile"
  role = "${aws_iam_role.server_role.name}"
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer. I think I still have a lot of gap in term of knowledge in this area. e.g. this is the first time I learn about `aws_iam_instance_profile`